# How to store all distinct permutations in a list from a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I want to create a recursive function, that either generates distinct permutatins, or stores and returns them and in a list.

I have found this code on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/ :

```
def shouldSwap(string, start, curr):
    for i in range(start, curr):
        if string[i] == string[curr]:
            return False
    return True


# Prints all distinct permutations
# in str[0..n-1]
def findPermutations(string, index, n):
    if index >= n:
        print(''.join(string))
        return

    for i in range(index, n):

        # Proceed further for str[i] only
        # if it doesn't match with any of
        # the characters after str[index]
        check = shouldSwap(string, index, i)
        if check:
            string[index], string[i] = string[i], string[index]
            findPermutations(string, index + 1, n)
            string[index], string[i] = string[i], string[index]
```

But I need to edit it in a way, that it is returning the list of the permutations.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to edit it yourself? What problems did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the function to become a generator and convert the result to a list.  That would require only two changes:

Change  `print(''.join(string))` to  `yield ''.join(string)`

and insert `yield from` in front of `findPermutations(string, index + 1, n)`

You can then use it as parameter to the list constructor:

```
result = list(findPermutations(list("abc"),0,3)
```

However, that function is way too complex and cumbersome.  You could get the same result with a simpler one that avoids the need to convert the input to a list and  supply extra parameters.

```
def permute(string):
    if len(string)==1: yield string;return
    for i,c in enumerate(string):
        yield from (c+rest for rest in permute(string[:i]+string[i+1:]))

result = list(permute("abc"))

# ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```